# run a script using windows cmd with predefiden stdinput at the time of execution

Tags: windows, shell

Say I have a python script that is similar to following:

```
name = input("what is your name?")
age = input("what is your age?")
print name, age
```

How can we execute that from from windows cmd with predefined name and age as input?
I have tried following:

```
python t23.py > x.txt | echo "sadaf" & echo "12"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P name=Enter your name: 
SET /P age=Please enter your age: 
python t23.py name age 2>&1 | tee output_file.txt
```

I am not tested it before this code but i think you will get some clue on my code ....